# Fullscreen Div - Scrollable - Responsive - Crossbrowser - Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a way to create a `div` with height and width of the current browser window size.

This should work even if the window is re-sized.
The fullscreen div shall be followed by even more content.
I am using Bootstrap3 - But I am not sure if this changes anything.

It is pretty easy to get this working in Firefox/Chrome/IE

```
.fullscreen {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This does not work on Safari.

So I came up with some js

```
$('.fullscreen').css({
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height()
    });
```

This works on all Browsers (At least all Browsers I've tested). Resizing the window does not work, as the width and height is fix. I could create a Listener that reacts on Window Size changes (I have not looked it up - but this should work).

I don't like the idea of using js to set css.

Isn't there a best practice? This should be possible using css only, shouldn't it? The solutions I've found on the web, were not satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ55H/)

You need to set the dimensions of both the viewport (`html`) and content (`body`) to 100%, then by giving a `div` a height and width of `100%` it will be calculated relative to the viewport, giving the functionality you require (always filling it even on resize).

Feel free to ignore the huge parrot picture in the example, I added it because often in such layouts the first `div` includes a responsive image.

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div>More Content</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div:first-of-type {
    height:100%; /* <-- keep the div 100% of the viewport height */
    width:100%; /* <-- keep the div 100% of the viewport width */
    background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSbcnkIVXLz23PALu8JD-cTGe8KbXKC1JV0gBM_x1lx3JyaNqE7);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}
div:last-of-type {
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I missed the html,body part. This fixed it. Thanks for the explanation.